Does Ezekiel 37:25-26 prove that the messiah would maintain the law/
In Ezekiel it mentions David who shall be king over them and will faithfully follow G-d's laws and statues, is this verse Messianic and does it affirm that the messiah would maintain the law?

My servant David shall be king over them; there shall be one shepherd
for all of them. They shall follow My rules and faithfully obey My
laws.
Thus they shall remain in the land that I gave to My servant Jacob and
in which your ancestors dwelt; they and their children and their
children’s children shall dwell there forever, with My servant David
as their prince for all time.


This passage alongside many others demonstrate the revival of Torah in Jerusalem. That in fact is the hallmark of the messianic era, that all will know about God (Jeremiah 31), that all will flock to Zion to learn Torah (Isaiah 2, Micah 4). It is no surprise the messiah himself will keep Torah. See Ezekiel 45:22 which says messiah will bring an offering in the Temple during Pesach for his and the community's sin

"In Ezekiel it mentions David who shall be king over them ..." (my emphasis). Could you elaborate in the question, who 'them' is referring to?

"... is this verse Messianic and does it affirm that the messiah would maintain the law?" (1) Could you elaborate in the question, why you think the verse might not be Messianic? (2) Could you elaborate in the question, why you think that, even if the verse is Messianic, it might not affirm that the messiah will maintain the [Jewish] law?

I was merely wondering

@ConnorJones If you are wondering, it means you have reason to think otherwise. If so, please elaborate on your uncertainties. Otherwise, where is the question?

“Is this messianic” is code for a particular form of messianism that has caused unmeasurable harm to Jews

Connor, come on. You’re not accomplishing anything. We’ve been onto you for your entire short career on this site, and onto people like you for the past two millennia. Even if we weren’t, you’re so bad at lying about your intentions that we’d have figured it out anyway. Leave and do something useful for society.

Hi @QwertyCTRL.I am not a missionary nor a Christian, I reject Jesus as the messiah and I always will, I am looking to convert to the Jewish faith, I am asking because as someone who grew up in a Christian family, I want to learn more about Judaism, I am not a Christian or a follower of Christ or a preacher, I reject those things, I'm in search of the real Jewish messiah.

Anytime you have a question on a verse: first check it out on Sefaria.org with the Jewish commentaries.
You have been TIME AFTER TIME asked to stop bringing Christian stuff here.
But for the fun of it: that the law cannot, and will not, be changed is baked into the Five Books of Moses itself. A prophet who claims to change the law is considered a false prophet. It is one of Maimonides' 13 Fundamentals of Jewish Faith.
So nobody is asking, "how do we know the Messiah won't change the law?", and therefore running to Ezekiel for an answer. Moses made it clear that the law won't change. Malachi's send-off message said "keep the teachings of Moses."
By the time of Ezekiel (read it in context!!), the Jews had been split into two kingdoms -- one with a Davidic king, one with a non-Davidic king -- for several centuries, and weren't doing a great job of keeping the law. So he's telling them that there will be a future time when there will be a united kingdom, under a Davidic king, and they will keep the law. And yes, that is a Messianic vision.
But it is not a "proof text" per se that the law won't change, as we don't need one.

I am not.a Christian, I reject Jesus as the messiah.
